# Error : module 'numpy.linalg' has no attribute 'lapack_lite' al utilizar la libreria pyFAI

Tags: numpy, python-3.9

Hoy descargué Anaconda Navigator para poder utilizar python en un nuevo ordenador y compilar un código que ya tenía en otro ordenador y funcionaba bien pero obtengo el siguiente error:

module 'numpy.linalg' has no attribute 'lapack_lite'

este error sale de la función pyFAI.load(FILE.poni). pyFAI es una librería de python para convertir imágenes que también descargué hoy en el nuevo ordenador. Pero creo que puede ser un problema de la versión de numpy (ahora tengo la versión numpy 1.22.1 y la versión pyFAI-0.20.0 silx-1.0.0 de pyFAI) . He probado a desinstalar y volver a instalar numpy pero no encuentro la solución, me sigue dando el mismo error.

sabe alguien sobre este error?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO **en español**!  Lamento comunicarte que las preguntas en inglés no son bien aceptadas, para eso esta el SO en inglés.  Plantéate traducirla antes de que la cierren por eso, gracias. De paso léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender como funcionamos y podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: No olvides traducir también el título :) Mostrá las versiones de tus librerías, ya que sin esos detalles es complicado ayudar.

Comment: No se apenas nada de python, pero las veces que lo he usado en nuevas maquinas he visto que su alias no siempre apuntaba a la version de python que yo pensaba, y cuando he instalado modulos lo mismo, se han instalado en otra version, teniendo que forzar la instalación en la version deseada... No se si por ahi van los tiros, pero compruebalo a ver.

Comment: hola, muchas gracias ya funciona. Probé a instalar otra versión pero no me permitía, aún así desinstalando numpy y volviendolo a instalar con la última versión disponible (1.22.1) ya me funciona el código :)